# Fetch records from timestamp column grouping by Month and Year in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a date column(timestamp datatype) and I want to fetch all the records and show it(descending) in the format of month and year.

```
For e.g.

Created Date   Amount
Oct 2015       2000
Mar 2015       5000
Jun 2014       4000
Jan 2014       1000
```

I tried the following query in MySQL but no luck.

```
SELECT Month(created_at) AS month, Year(created_at) AS year, SUM(final_amount) AS amount
FROM sales
GROUP BY month, year
```

I am not able to get by Year and Month both. Results are grouped by Year. Here is the output.

```
month   year   amount
10      2015   7000
6       2014   5000
```

Comment: so exactly what is the problem with this, other than you're not doing any `sort by`?

Comment: I guess it's the (missing) ORDER BY that's the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`created_at`, '%b %Y') AS `mY`, SUM(`final_amount`) AS `amount` FROM `sales` GROUP BY `mY`
```

Comment: Thanks. Appreciated!! How can I sort by based on month and year now?

Comment: add to query ORDER BY `created_at` DESC

Answer (score 0):

Check out this fiddle.  It turns your two columns into dates and sorts by that.  Change asc to desc to reverse the sort order.  If this isn't what you were looking for, you might want to show us what the DESIRED output should look like.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d83c3/4